# Помогите составить регулятор выражение в URL ссылке Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть URL такого типа

> "localhost:6000/name/:id"

где id это число.

Т.е.

> "localhost:6000/name/:1245", "localhost:6000/name/:3567"

являются правильными вариантами.

Но к примеру

> "localhost:6000/name/:1245gfh", "localhost:6000/name/:",
>   "localhost:6000/name/:fdf1234"

должны игнорироваться.

Пытался сделать сам, но такой вариант компилятору не нравится `/name/:\d/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**\d** означает 1 цифру, чтобы захватить больше нужно использовать **\d+**, так же чтоб отбросить вариант 1232asdasd нужно указать конец **$**

т.е. должно быть: **\d+$**

Comment: Отлично, с этим я разобрался. А что касаемо текста вначале? В URL должен присутствовать в начале вот такой текст '/name/:' и уже после него \d+$ Как это оформляется?

Comment: У вас всё правильно, так и оформляется **/name/\d+$**

Comment: Дело в том, что символ '/' в середине /name/\d+$/ будто мешает, и поэтому я не могу получить правильный результат

Comment: дополни вопрос с примером того какая строка и регулярка на входе не отрабатывает

Comment: в данном случае "/name/:" это строка, которая должна быть всегда, к примеру если я введу "/noname/:", то это должно не обработать, дело в том, что в тексте у меня есть символы '/'. в этом вся проблема. Если убрать символы '/' в тексте, то все работает.

Comment: `/` не является спец символом в регулярке как и `:` так что точно дело не в них, точнее не в их присутствии. Ещё раз дополните вопрос с конкретным примером входной строки

Comment: вот пример "/name/:1234"

Comment: если регулярка такая `/name/\d+$/` то ошибка тут в том что после символа `$` идёт  `/`

Comment: так регулярка начинается с -> / и заканчивается -> /

Comment: ладно, мой косяк, плохо донёс, регулярка тут `/name/:\d+$` так как у Вас в js она определяется в `/<regex>/` то внутри все `/` должны быть экранированы `\/`

Comment: о даааа, это то что нужно! спасибо большое)